# How to read single values that contains commas in csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that contains the following values

```
"Spam2,pank",Spam3,Spam6,Spam7
Spam1,Spam5,Spam0,Spam9
```

And i am using the following python code to read a particular column

```
for line in open('D:\eggs2.csv','rb'):
    columns = line.split(",")
    print columns[0]
```

The output it gives is:-

```
"Spam2
Spam1
```

while i am expecting :

```
Spam2,pank
Spam1
```

Please Help me out on this.

Comment: check out http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html

Comment: import csv and let that do the parsing for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to reinvent the wheel, the python csv module does a perfect job.

```
import csv

csv_file = open('D:\eggs2.csv','rb')
csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
for row in csv_reader:
    print row[0]

csv_file.close()
```

@see [python csv](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what data structure you want to red the csv into. This will load the data into a list of tuples. Each line will be an entry in the list and each line will be a tuple of string values.

I'd  create a helper function for reading files I use this all the time

```
def readfile(filepath, delim):     
   with open(filepath, 'r') as f:         
      return [tuple(line.split(delim)) for line in f] 

data = readfile('D:\eggs2.csv', ',')
```

There are beneftis of using with (it handles the closing, excpetions e.t.c) but you'll need to be on Python 2.7+

If you want to use a '|' delimeter or somthing else in the future you don't have to re-write your code.

Answer (score -1):

You could split it twice. First, split it to get something like `'''"\w"'''`, ie all alphanumberic characters inside quotes. The result is a list for each split. Then you would split again, this time for `','`, for each list that resulted in your first split. Then you flatten the lists.